# How to justify text like poem?

Tags: android, alignment, justify

I want to align left and right every sentence like a poem in Android Studio.
Please see attached image.
Below poem has 4 lines.
Last word of the each and every line should be align right, and the rest should align left.
I'm doing these things in Main_Activity.java file.

[image: click here to see the Image]

Comment: Share your idea and/or code in order to help you better, please

Answer (score 0):

[image: Layout]

Split the line and keep the two parts in separate `TextView` objects. Just align them to the left and right of the `parent` which is a `RelativeLayout`, so I suppose this will work.